# Using And Adding Vue Components On Runtime

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two components named Header and Link and I am using TypeScript with VueJS. You can see the component content below

-- Header.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="cHeader">
        {{content}}
    </div> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { TextBase } from "./TextControls"
import { Enums } from "./Enums"
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Header extends TextBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.type = "header";
        this.content = "Add Header Here";
        this.textAlign = Enums.TextAlign.Center;
    }
} 
</script>
```

-- Link.vue

```
<template>
    <a v-bind:href="href" v-bind:target="target">Click Me!</a>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { TextBase } from "./TextControls"
    import { Enums } from "./Enums"
    import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class Link extends TextBase {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.href = "#";
            this.target = Enums.HrefTarget.None;
            this.type = "link";
        }

        public href: string;
        public target: string;
    }
</script>
```

When I want to add these components by pushing into an array they does not render properly. You can see the sample below how i am tryşng to import my components

--Document.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="documentContainer">
       <div v-for="c in components" class="component">
           <component :is="c.type"></component>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";
    import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import { ComponentBase } from "../components/TextControls"
    import Header from "../components/Header.vue"
    import Link from "../components/Link.vue"
    @Component
    export default class Document extends Vue {

        public components: Array<any> = [];
        constructor(){
            super();
            create(Header);
            create(Link);
        }
        create<T>(type: (new () => T)): void {
            let t = new type();
            this.components.push(t);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Normally it should be two components in v-for looped div tag but it does not run. Do you have any advise of way to render these components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after a while.

First : Don't use original tag names as component name (i used header and link)

Second : I used the template below in document.vue file

```
<div v-for="c in components" class="component">
     <component v-bind:is="c.type"></component>
</div>
```